# Expandable p tag does not expands as expecting manner while copy pasting the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, perfect-scrollbar

I have a contenteditable p tag which expands til a particular height and then it will have a scrollbar. When copy pasting the content inside that expandable p tag it does not expand or sometimes it will expands beyond the height limit.

HTML:

`<p contenteditable = true id = "expand" class = "editable">`

CSS:

```
     .editable{
         min-height: 60px;
         ...
     }
```

Comment: You have spaces between attribute and values. Try `<p contenteditable="true" id="expand" class="editable"></p>` without the spaces?

Comment: It's my typing mistake. Sorry it was correct in my code.